# Install ipykernel in vscode - ipynb (Jupyter)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Greetings!
I am not able to install ipykernel and receiving following error. Please advise.

print('Hello')

Running cells with 'Python 3.10.5 64-bit' requires ipykernel package.
Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment.
Command: 'c:/Users/ps98/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe -m pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'c:/Users/ps98/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe -m
> pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall'

Error reports tell you what to do.

Run the command in your terminal:

```
pip install ipykernel
```

At the same time, of course, make sure that the pylance extension is installed.