# "pip install ipykernel --upgrade" does not work after "running cells with python 3.11 requires ipykernel package" (in visio studio code)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions

Like in [Install ipykernel in vscode - ipynb (Jupyter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72628465/install-ipykernel-in-vscode-ipynb-jupyter) and [Python requires ipykernel to be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997553/python-requires-ipykernel-to-be-installed)

It requires to install "ipykernel package" while running Jupyter in visio Code.

**Running cells with 'Python 3.11.0b5 64-bit' requires ipykernel package.
Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment.
Command: 'c:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe -m pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall'**

However, "pip install ipykernel" or "pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall" does not work. I searched other solutions, none resolves this problem till now. with the following warning:

PS C:\workspace\code\py> pip install ipykernel --upgrade

**WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/ipykernel/**

.....

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipykernel (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ipykernel
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip**

Would you please shed light on how to resolve it?

BTW, both pip and python are the latest

**PS C:\workspace\code\py> pip --version
pip 22.2 from C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)**

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue downloading Microsoft C++ Building Tools and after that I installed "pip install ipykernel". Everything is running perfect.

[Microsoft C++ Building Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJUkx.png)

[image: acreenshot]